# llamar informacion de otro form

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Necesito llamar los datos que se encuentran en otro form, ¿esto es posible?, publico un código resumen.
Utilizo esto es Java + JSF + Primefaces
Cuando busco los valores de tramiteBean.descripcion, me llega null.
Gracias

```
<p:tabView id="tab">
    <p:tab title="Nuevo">
        <h:form id="form1">
            <p:textEditor value="#{tramiteBean.descripcion}"  id="descripcion"/>    
            <p:inputNumber value="#{tramiteBean.idTipo}"  id="tipo"/>   
        </h:form>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="Enviar">
        <h:form id="form2">
            <p:commandButton style="width:100px" value="Enviar" actionListener="#{controlador.tramiteFinalizarInterno}" update=":tab:form1"/> 
        </h:form>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Comment: ya intentaste jalar los valores mediante js/jquery?

Comment: no, pero igualmente debo llamarlos con algún botón y no puedo llegar al form1

Comment: te recomiendo intentarlo mediante js, de otra manera solo se envia lo de un formulario al backend. Otra cosa que puedes intentar son los campos ocultos pero es mala solucion.

Comment: me puedes enviar algún ejemplo por favor?

Comment: no puedo aunque quisiera no tengo tu contacto, intenta hacerlo y actualiza tu pregunta para que alguien te ayude con lo que te falte.

Comment: deberías intentarlo agregando los campos en el form 2 en oculto.  el equivalente a hidden en html

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación oficial de primeface [Link Button](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/linkButton.xhtml?jfwid=f1ef4) con este tipo de boton puedes enviar parametros.

```
<div class="card">
    <p:linkButton outcome="productDetail" value="Bookmark" style="margin-right:20px;">
        <f:param name="productId" value="10"/>
    </p:linkButton>

    <p:linkButton outcome="productDetail" value="Bookmark new tab" style="margin-right:20px;" target="_blank">
        <f:param name="productId" value="10"/>
    </p:linkButton>

    <p:linkButton outcome="productDetail" value="With Icon" icon="pi pi-star" style="margin-right:20px;">
        <f:param name="productId" value="20"/>
    </p:linkButton>

    <p:linkButton outcome="productDetail" icon="pi pi-star" style="margin-right:20px;" title="Icon Only">
        <f:param name="productId" value="30"/>
    </p:linkButton>

    <p:linkButton outcome="productDetail" value="With Icon" disabled="true" style="margin-right:20px;">
        <f:param name="productId" value="40"/>
    </p:linkButton>

    <p:linkButton outcome="productDetail" value="Bookmark" icon="pi pi-star" disabled="true"
                  style="margin-right:20px;">
        <f:param name="productId" value="50"/>
    </p:linkButton>

    <p:linkButton outcome="productDetail" icon="pi pi-star" style="margin-right:20px;" disabled="true"
                  title="Icon Only">
        <f:param name="productId" value="60"/>
    </p:linkButton>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias por responder, pero no puedo ver el llamado del otro form, esta opción no me ha funcionado, he leído la documentación